# jq - how to use multiple env variables to get data from JSON

Tags: environment-variables, jq

So, if I have a JSON object like this in a data.json file:

```
{
  "a1": {
    "b1": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    }
  }
}
```

I can do something like:

```
VAR1="a1"
jq --arg v1 "$VAR1" '.[$v1]."b1"' data.json
```

and get those key1 and key2.

I want to do the same thing like above but with using two variables:

```
VAR1="a1"
VAR2="b1"
```

And something like below is not working:

```
jq --arg v1 "$VAR1" --arg v2 "$VAR2" '.[$v1].[$v2]' data.json
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the inner dot:

```
jq --arg v1 "$VAR1" --arg v2 "$VAR2" '.[$v1][$v2]' data.json
```